# Emails with empty content-id

Tags: jakarta-mail, mime, rfc822

I sometimes recieve e-mails with empty CONTENT-ID.

Exemple:

[image: Empty content-id, Content-Disposition: attachement]

In most cases, the empty content-id belongs to an attachement, that is added to the email two times, once as correct **inline** attachement with a content ID, in the second, the content-disposition is : **attachement** instead and the content ID is empty.

[image: Content-Disposition: inline]

Is this a mail client bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the MIME RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) a Content-ID is optional, but if present should be "world-unique" (which an empty string certainly isn't).

Personally I'd treat empty Content-ID to be identical to a missing Content-ID.

Comment: And yes, it's probably a mail client bug that it's adding the attachment twice.  Possibly they're trying to work around bugs in mail readers that don't handle inline parts correctly.